# jquery mobile dialog closes after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

folks, i've got a problem i'm hoping someone can help with.  when my jquery mobile app loads, it checks with my server to see if a native app exists for the platform the user is on.  if it does, i pop a dialog asking if they'd like to download the native app.  here is the problem, it doesn't seem to matter where i put this check, when the page finishes loading in mobile safari, the dialog disappears.  here is my code to start the check:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  checkRedirect();
});
```

but i've also tried in the pageinit and pagecreate.  checkRedirect() makes an ajax call and based on the result pops the dialog with a "$.mobile.changePage"

it seems the browser still thinks the original page is loading and then somehow dismisses the dialog when the page is done loading.  sorry i don't have more details.  i think what i need is an event that happens after the whole page is loaded (and after all ajax background loading), but i haven't been able to find that.  any help or suggestions is appreciated.

UPDATE: after a discussion with Omar, it turned out that using a "Popup" instead of a dialog worked for what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, using `.ready()` in jQuery Mobile isn't correct, use jQuery Mobile events.

You need to delay opening dialog/popup once any page event occur to make sure that the page is fully loaded.

```
setTimeout(function () {
 $.mobile.changePage('#dialog');
}, 50);
```

---

#### update:

Based on our discussion, using jQM popup widget is more reliable in your case.

Comment: i tried that... it works as long as the delay is more than the amount of time the page is loading... so i could set the timeout for a long time, but then that still seems fragile...

Comment: is there an event that is triggered after the browser thinks it is done loading the page?

Comment: @johnellis A dialog is a page but in shape of a dialog. You can do it in one event `pagebeforechange`. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/88THT/

Comment: the problem is, i can't eat the default condition because i don't know right away that i'm gonna pop the dialog... i only know after an ajax call...  i guess i could make the ajax call synchronous...  is that what i have to do?

Comment: @johnellis `pageshow` is triggered after page is loaded, but I still think you may need to delay checking for milliseconds. **Edit:** if you intend to use `pageshow` use `.one` not `.on`, as you need it to fire once only. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CUt6n/

Comment: i don't think you are understanding... i can't do the "preventDefault" because i don't know right away if i want to do that or not... the problem doesn't happen with jsfiddle, but i created a small page here: http://mwa.dovevalleygolf.com/test.html  if you go there on an iPhone you will likely see the problem... then you can view the src.

Comment: @johnellis i forgot to remove `preventDefault()` it is intended to be used with `pagebeforechange`.

Comment: if you have an iOS device, you can see the problem with that link i put above... it is a scaled down version of what i'm trying to do... but now i'm thinking i just use `asyn: false` on my ajax call and do it in `pagebeforechange` and then return `preventDefault`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41722/discussion-between-omar-and-john-ellis)